# On Apache Camel, is it possible to setup a second route to consume information from previous route, but at a different schedule?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm new to Apache Camel. In my application, I need to consume information from files on a folder, make validations and store that resulting information on an object that is stored inside the exchange, on a property. This process must run every 3 hours a day.

But, I need only once a day at a scheduled time to send an email with the information that is stored on that object. How can I achieve this?

Here's some pseudo code:

*.1* from("file:C:/SourceFolder?scheduler.cron=* 3 * * * *).aggregate().process().to(**a**);  //every 3 hours;

*.2* from(**a**).process();  //here, the email must be send at 8pm every day;

Component "Direct" doesn't work, as it doesn't accept scheduling. I just need the information on the exchange from *.1*, and I need the routing *.2* to run only once a day. Suggestions please? Thank you.

Comment: Does this help? - https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/scheduler-component.html#_sample

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. We are going to store the values we need from the first route on static variables and consume them with an independent scheduled service (Quartz).